# Rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

I'm trying to build my CMake project in Visual Studio 2019, but all of a sudden, after using this exact make file and setup for almost two weeks, it throws the error-

```
rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
```

I didn't even know I was using ninja, didn't know it was installed and I haven't had any problems before. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have the same exact issue.  I use the same local Android SDK and NDK packages, libraries, compiler etc.  Nothing has changed, yet somehow, as soon as I connect to the internet and run a build, the defaults have magically changed. Failed to run MSBuild.exe to get the value of VCTargetsPath.  Same on all 6 of my Windows boxes. How do we insure that the Android SDK / Gradle version doesn't change?

Answer (score 2):

Today I had an error like this, in Android Studio, and I found no solution, then I got angry and seeing that it said that there was an inconsistency in the projectandroid/app/.cxx folder, I went to file explorer, made show hidden files and deleted that folder, I went and cleaned the project and that was the solution LOL, if someone happens that, this can solve!

Comment: For me, it was: press "clean" button in Builder, then "rebuild", then "build".

Answer (score 0):

It can be CMake cannot link to the include directories and the libraries. You can consider add the prefix path of those files in the CMakeList. For example:

```
set( OpenCV_DIR "E:/OpenCV/opencv/build" )    
set( OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR "E:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include" )
```

Answer (score 0):

make the "cmake-build-debug" folder visible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).